Isolated Eigenvalues of Finite Multiplicity in the Spectrum of a Self-Adjoint Operator with Compact Perturbation
I am studying spectral properties of operators, specifically working through Ronald G. Douglas' "Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory." While doing exercise 5.15, I encountered the following statement:
If $H$ is a self-adjoint operator on $\mathscr{H}$ and $K$ is a compact operator on $\mathscr{H}$, then $\sigma(H+K) \setminus \sigma(H)$ consists of isolated eigenvalues of finite multiplicity.
Here, $\sigma(T)$ denotes the spectrum of an operator $T$. My current understanding is based on the fact that the essential spectra of $H$ and $H+K$ are the same. However, I am struggling to understand how to rigorously show that the isolated eigenvalues of finite multiplicity arise in $\sigma(H+K)$ due to the compact perturbation $K$.
Any insights or detailed explanations on these points would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The sets $\sigma(H+K)=\sigma(H)$ may coincide. It may occur that $H+K$ does not admit any eigenvalues.

You know that $\sigma_{\rm ess}(H+K)=\sigma_{\rm ess}(H)\subset\sigma(H)$. Then
$$
\sigma(H+K)\setminus\sigma(H)\subset\sigma(H+K)\setminus \sigma_{\rm ess}(H)=\sigma(H+K)\setminus \sigma_{\rm ess}(H+K).
$$
So now you are left with proving that elements in the spectrum which are not in the essential spectrum are isolated eigenvalues of finite multiplicity. Or, equivalently, with showing that both accumulation points of the spectrum and eigenvalues of infinite multiplicity are in the essential spectrum.

Edit: About the last assertion, I'll try to provide a more conceptual answer later. But here is one argument. We may assume without loss of generality tha $\lambda=0$. If $0$ is an accumulation point for $\sigma(H)$, then for very $\delta>0$ the set $R_\delta=\sigma(H)\cap(-\delta,\delta)$ is infinite. Then Borel functional calculus allows us to produce infinitely many pairwise orthogonal subprojecitions of $1_{R_\delta}(H)$. This means that $P_\delta=1_{R_\delta}(H)$ is infinite. As such it is not compact, and so its image in the Calkin is nonzero. So the inequality $-\delta P_\delta\leq HP\leq\delta P$ survives in the Calkin. This implies that $0\in\sigma_{\rm ess}(H)$, for the $H$ is invertible, there would exist $\delta>0$ such that $|H|\geq\delta$, and so $|H|P\geq\delta P$ for every projection $P$.

Thank you for your answers. However, I am still having difficulty proving that 'accumulation points of the spectrum are in the essential spectrum.' Could you offer some suggestions to help clarify this?

I have edited an argument into the answer.
